# How to filter a list of invoices that contains a "TV" item in its nested List of items- using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of "Invoices" object. and Within this array ,there is a nested array of "Items".
Example:

```
[
   {
      "invoiceNo":"10",
      "customerId":"101",
      "invoiceTotal":"2500",
      "items":[
         {
            "itemId":"1",
            "itemName":"TV"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"2",
            "itemName":"Laptop"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"3",
            "itemName":"PC"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "invoiceNo":"11",
      "customerId":"102",
      "invoiceTotal":"7500",
      "items":[
         {
            "itemId":"2",
            "itemName":"Laptop"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"3",
            "itemName":"PC"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to return only array of all invoices that contains "TV" item.

The following is my code

```
let text = queryText.toLowerCase();
    return this.http
      .get<Invoices[]>(
        this.url + "/crm-operations/application/invoices",
        { headers: headerInfo }
      )
      .pipe(
        map((invoicesData) =>
        invoicesData.filter((invoice) => {
            if (invoice.items) {
              invoice.items.filter((row) => { 
                 row.itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text)>-1;
              });
            }
          })
        )
      );
```

The result is always an empty array
IT must return an array with the invoice number "10" object.
What is wrong is my code. and is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: `array.filter` takes a predicate (A function that returns true/false). Both your predicates return void, which I think javascript coerces into false. `array.filter(_ -> false)` will aways return an empty array `[ ]`

Comment: you need return your second filter, data.filter(i => {
   return i.items && i.items.filter(f => f.itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf("tv") > -1).length
})

Comment: Nonik I changed my code as you suggested , but it returns all invoices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the body of your `map` operator to this:

```
invoicesData.filter((invoice) =>
  // (1)
  invoice.items?.some((row) => // (2)
    // (3)
    row.itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text)>-1
  )
)
```

**(1)** removes curly braces to return the value (`true`/`false`) of `invoice.items?.some(..)`

**(2)** instead of `filter` we use `some`. It's a bit more efficient since it doesn't iterate over all remaining array items once the inner function returns `true` for some item.

**(3)** removes curly braces to implicitly return the result of `row.itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text)>-1`

Comment: Thank you so much kruschid. You solved my problem. Thank you soooo much

Comment: You've done a very nice job of explaining this.  I see a lot of answers on SO that have correct code but don't explain why it works.

Comment: Thank you Linda, I'm always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.pipe` code like here:

```
  .pipe(
        map((invoicesData) =>
        invoicesData.filter((invoice) => {
            if (invoice.items.length) {
              return invoice.items.filter((row) => { 
                 row.itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text)>-1;
              }).length;
            }
            return false;
          })
        )
      );
```